# python: speed up double iterator loop that accesses neighboring elements

Tags: python, loops, opencv, filtering

I have an implementation of a median filter:

```
def medianFilter(src, size):
    pad = int(size/2)
    src_padded = cv2.copyMakeBorder(src,pad,pad,pad,pad,cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
    for i,j in itertools.product(xrange(src.shape[0]), xrange(src.shape[1])):
        src[i][j] = np.median(src_padded[i:i+size, j:j+size]) 

    return src
```

Is this the optimal implementation or are there more Pythonic ways to achieve this that may be faster?

Some clarification: the `cv2.copyMakeBorder` adds a `pad` sized frame to the image along each edge so that when we look for `size`x`size` sub images for border pixels, we don't end up out of bounds.

EDIT: I know OpenCV medianBlur exists and is faster. I am asking for speedups to these kind of operations in particular

Comment: OpenCV [medianBlur](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html#gsc.tab=0) ?

Comment: @Miki Haha no I know that. I'm asking for speedups to double loops like this.

Comment: in general on double loops, or you want apply some kernel in a convolution?

Comment: @Miki No convolution. In general double loops and slicing in nested loops.

Comment: You can speed this up by writing your own code to walk the matrix and compute the median, keeping partial counts and median candidates for each sub-matrix.  It burns a lot of storage, and saves little unless *size* is sufficiently large.  This is Pythonic only in that you can wrap all the dirty details inside the median_filter method.